# Is a Cambodian visa on arrival available at the Chong Sa Ngam / Anlong Veng crossing from Thailand?

Tags: borders, thailand, visas-on-arrival, cambodia, land-borders

It looks like I'm probably crossing from Laos to Thailand in the next few days. I'll be using my 14 days in Thailand to head for Cambodia and I'm considering my options.

I can find that there's a border crossing at Chong Sa Ngam / Anlong Veng but so far I can't verify whether Cambodia offers visa-on-arrival service at that crossing or not.

Comment: Please be aware that Thai Immigration has been quite strict of recent in regard to people crossing the border.  Do not be surprised if they ask you to document your exit plans, as well as financial means of support.

Comment: I had no problem last time I entered Thailand, on foot from Malaysia last December.

Comment: Last December is a long time ago ;-)  After the Ratchaprasong bomb incident last month where it was discovered that suspects crossed the border improperly, things have been tightened up quite a bit.  Because Immigration got caught with its pants down, they have been dotting their i's and crossing their t's a bit more carefully.

Comment: That makes sense. Here in Vientiane there's a lot of Africans who were working in Thailand and hit some visa problems in some kind of crackdown after that incident.

Comment: In any case I'll be leaving Thailand at the obscure border crossing. I'll be entering at a major crossing.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes. VOA is available at this border crossing.**

I finally found [an official website listing this crossing](http://www.tourismcambodia.com/tripplanner/essential-information/visa-passport.htm) with a very different spelling and it clearly states you can get a visa on arrival:

> **The entry points to obtain Visa:**
>   Cambodia-Thailand border:
>   **Choam Sanguam** International Check Point (Banteay Meanchey Province)